# How can I create a thread pool in Java that creates a new thread on each run?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Here's my situation: I'm working on some single-threaded code. The code is stochastic, and I need to run many instances of it to get an idea of the average. To make life easier and faster, my current solution is to use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`. Now, the problem is that each thread needs to have its own independent data. The way I originally implemented this is like so:

```java
public class Data {
    private static Map<Thread, Data> instanceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Thread, Data>();

    public static Data getInstance() {
        if (!instanceMap.containsKey(Thread.currentThread()))
            instanceMap.put(Thread.currentThread(), new Data());
        return instanceMap.get(Thread.currentThread());
    }

    private Data() {
    }
}
```

This is fine when the number of iterations <= number of threads. But, when I'm running 20 iterations using 8 threads, there's a problem. Because those 8 threads will be reused to run those 20 iterations, `instanceMap` will only ever contain 8 instances.

So what's the *correct* way to handle something like this? What I really need is a thread pool that kills off threads after each iteration. Is there a way to kill off the thread in the `run` method of the `Runnable` object that's given to `ExecutorService.submit`? Is there some alternative to `newFixedThreadPool` I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JB Nizet's answer is good, but given what you have, another approach might be to wrap your existing `Runnable` inside another `Runnable` or `Callable` which removes the `Data` object after the original `Runnable` runs:

```
class DataRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Runnable child;

    DataRunnable(Runnable aChild) { child = aChild; }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        child.run();
        Data.removeOldDataForThisThread();
    }
}
```

Let me add that your `Data.getInstance()` method could be simplified somewhat by using a `ThreadLocal` object to hold the instances:

```
public class Data {
    private static ThreadLocal<Data> datas = new ThreadLocal<Data>() {
        @Override
        protected Data initialValue() { return new Data(); }
    };

    public static Data getInstance() {
        return datas.get();
    }

    public static void removeOldDataForThisThread() { datas.remove(); }

    private Data() {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really great! I didn't know about `ThreadLocal`. I like your solution. I think I may end up essentially doing that. Due to the way my code is structured, this is much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: I went with your solution, and it was relatively simple to implement. This is a really big project with a lot of working parts, and JB's solution would've required a bit of refactoring to make work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that you're storing data that is local to a task executed by some thread in a global map. Just scope the data to the task, and everything will be much simpler:

```
Callable<Foo> task = new Callable<Foo>() {
    private Data data = new Data();

    public Foo call() {
        // execute your task here, using the task's data
    }
});

executorService.submit(task);
```

Comment: +1 dude.  I would have shown a `Callable` object whose constructor shows the data passing in which is easier to understand.